# How to edit content in a about:blank iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to edit the content in a about:blank iframe.
I tried:

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML="<p>hello</p>";
```

And I get:

> Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `open` the document first, that will create the iframe in the DOM tree.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
iframe.contentDocument.open();
iframe.contentDocument.close();
iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello World!</h1>';
```

A working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jss81u0a/2/).

And it seems that `iframe.contentDocument` is equivalent with `iframe.contentWindow.document` in modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you! This is were I searched for!